# A simple drag and draw HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've written a quick directive that provides two features:

- Clicking on an empty area of the canvas will allow a 'drag and draw' function
- Clicking on a an existing rectangle on the canvas will allow a 'drag and drop' function.

The primary thing I would like feedback on is *whether my method for drawing and redrawing the canvas objects is the right way to do this.*

Essentially, I'm redrawing the entire canvas and all of its contained objects, every time the canvas changes (eg a shape is moved or resized).

Here's the code for the directive, and I'll put comments in the parts I'm more interested in feedback on:

```
app.directive('mycanvas', function($document){
    return {

        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            var gX = element[0].clientWidth, gY = element[0].clientHeight; 

            var ctx = element[0].getContext('2d'); 
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(100,0,0)";         

            var mouseDown = false;      //Physical mouse press down         
            var hasMouseover = false;   //Mouse is over an already drawn node

            var objs = [];

            var currentObj = {};

            function drawRect(r){
                ctx.fillRect(r.startX, r.startY, r.endX-r.startX,   r.endY-r.startY);
            }


            //??Is this the best way to do this? 
            function isWithinBounds(obj, x,y){    
                var oXmin, oXmax, oYmin, oYmax;
                if (obj.startX < obj.endX){
                    oXmin = obj.startX;
                    oXmax = obj.endX; 
                }
                else {
                    oXmin = obj.endX;
                    oXmax = obj.startX 
                }

                if (obj.startY < obj.endY){
                    oYmin = obj.startY;
                    oYmax = obj.endY;
                }
                else{
                    oYmin = obj.endY; 
                    oYmax = obj.startY; 
                }

                return (x > oXmin && x < oXmax && y > oYmin && y < oYmax);

            }

            //?? Redraws the entire thing. 
            //?? Would it be better to have a 'temporary' layer (ie a second canvas), to avoid having the redraw the inplace objects? 
            function redraw(){
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, gX, gY); 

                angular.forEach(objs, function(obj){
                    drawRect(obj); 
                });

                drawRect(currentObj); 
            }

            element.on('mousedown', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();

                if (hasMouseover){
                    //clickX/clickY - the position of the original click event, for the purposes of calculating the new drag position
                    currentObj.clickX = event.clientX-8;
                    currentObj.clickY = event.clientY-8;

                    objs = _.reject(objs, currentObj); 
                }
                else{
                    currentObj = {};
                    currentObj.startX = event.clientX-8; 
                    currentObj.startY = event.clientY-8; 
                }


                mouseDown = true; 
            }); 

            element.on('mouseup', function(event){
                event.preventDefault(); 
                objs.push(currentObj); 
                mouseDown = false; 
                //redraw();

            });

            element.on('mousemove', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();

                if (mouseDown){
                    if (hasMouseover){
                        //drag the object
                        var cx =event.clientX-8 , cy = event.clientY-8; 

                        var dx = cx - currentObj.clickX, dy = cy - currentObj.clickY; 

                        currentObj.clickX = cx;
                        currentObj.clickY = cy; 

                        currentObj.startX += dx; 
                        currentObj.endX += dx;
                        currentObj.startY += dy; 
                        currentObj.endY += dy; 

                    }
                    else{
                        //resize new object
                        currentObj.endX = event.clientX-8; 
                        currentObj.endY = event.clientY-8;
                    }
                    redraw();
                }

                else{
                    //Non-clicked mouse move - detect for mouse over only. 

                    var cx =event.clientX-8 , cy = event.clientY-8; 

                    if (hasMouseover){ //check current object first
                        if (isWithinBounds(currentObj, cx, cy)) return;     //break straight away
                    }

                    hasMouseover = false;

                    //Detect mouseover                  
                    for (var i = 0; i< objs.length; i++){
                        var obj = objs[i]; 
                        if (isWithinBounds(obj, cx, cy)){
                            hasMouseover = true;                            
                            currentObj = obj; 

                            break; 
                        }
                    }



                    if (hasMouseover) {
                        element.css({cursor: 'pointer'});
                    }
                    else{
                        element.css({cursor: 'auto'});
                    }                   
                }               
            }); 

        }

    };
});
```

There are those magic numbers everywhere (`-8`). Please ignore, I plan to tidy that up, for now I'm just wondering about the overall technique of drawing this canvas.